# Loday-Quillen-Tsygan Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, positive-characteristic

The Loday-Quillen-Tsygan states that for an associative algebra $A$ over a field of characteristic zero there is the isomorphism $H_* (gl(A)) \simeq \Lambda (HC_{*-1} (A))$. The proof heavily relies on char = $0$.
Where can I find a counterexample in positive characteristic?